# Why is The Entire Body of the Web page loaded to the table instead of the data when retrieving data from the database using ajax in Larvel

Tags: ajax, laravel, get, laravel-5.6

I have this table showing all the encashment records, it works fine but when I try to get the rows from the database within a specific range of dates and display it to the same table, the whole body of the webpage is being loaded to the table instead of the rows from the database.

**Please see image below:**

[image]

this is my function from the tableController.php

```
 function encashmentRecord_DateRange(Request $request){
    if($request->ajax())
    {
      $start = $request->get('startDate');
      $end = $request->get('endDate');
      $data = DB::table('encashment_requests')->whereBetween('date',[$start,$end])->get();
      return view('incashment',compact('data'));
    }
}
```

the script in my encashment.blade.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#dataTable').DataTable();

   $('#start_date').datepicker({
     format:'yyyy-mm-dd',
     autoclose:true
   }).val();

   $('#end_date').datepicker({
       format:'yyyy-mm-dd',
       autoclose:true
   }).val();

   var range = document.getElementById('btnrange');
   range.addEventListener('click',function(){
     var start_date = $('#start_date').val();
     var end_date =$('#end_date').val();
     alert(end_date);
     $('#dataTable').DataTable().destroy();
     listDateRange(start_date,end_date);
   },false);

   function listDateRange(startDate,endDate){
     $.ajax({
       method: 'GET',
       url : "{{ route('encashmentRecord.action') }}",
       data: {startDate:startDate, endDate:endDate},
       success:function(data)
       {
         alert(data);
         $('#dataTable').html(data);
       }
     })
   }
});
```

Comment: Could you paste an example of your controller method that's supposed to return the rows?

Comment: It is just showing what is returned by the route encashmentRecord.action, you have to update the function linked with this route

Comment: @NikoPeltoniemi, thank you for checking this question, I have added above the function 
that returns the rows in my controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the data, you shouldn't be returning view() from your controller.

Try replacing it with this: `return response()->json($data, 200);`

Answer (score 0):

I may have found the solution to my problem, though it may look lengthy. But it worked.
I made another view, encashmentRecord.blade, containing only the table, so in the controller, instead of returning the data in the incashment.blade, I returned the data to the new view, encashentRecord.blade and I use "@include('encashmentRecord')" in my incashment.blade to display the table.

encashmentRecord.blade.php

```
<div class="card-body">
 <table id="dataTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Account ID</th>
     <th class="sort">Date</th>
     <th>Desired Ammount</th>
     <th>Destination</th>
     <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    @if(isset($data))
     @foreach($data as $row)
      <tr>
       <td>{{ $row->account_name}}</td>
       <td>{{ $row->account_id}}</td>
       <td>{{ $row->created_at}}</td>
       <td>Php {{ $row->requested_ammount}}</td>
       <td>{{ $row->destination}}</td>
       <td>{{ $row->status}}</td>
      </tr>
     @endforeach
   @else
    <tr>
     No Data
    </tr>
  @endif
 </tbody>
</table>
```

and this is incashment.blade.php

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xl-3 ">
    <input type="text" name="query" id="start_date" class="form-control input_daterange">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 ">
    <input type="text" name="query" id="end_date" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 ">
    <button class="btn" id="btnrange">Go</button>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card" style="margin-bottom: 0px">
     <div class="card-header">
         Encashment Record
     </div>

     <div id="table_data">
        @include('tables.encashmentRecord')
     </div>
  </div>
```

I just change the view in my return on the controller

```
  return view('tables.encashmentRecord',compact('data'));
```